# inner join prepared sql statement in java

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm attempting to use a prepared statement to select a value from an SQL database.

My input, is an ID in the table Notification. I get an ID, because of this I can now get the DOCUMENT_ID for that ID in the Notification table.
The DOCUMENT_ID in the Notification table is the same as the DOCUMENT_ID in the Taxes table.
What i need to select is the DOCUMENT_TYPE from the Taxes table.

I have tried using inner join to link the two tables and get me my value but no dice.

can anyone help me with this select statement/query?

Comment: thanks guys, both methods worked really. much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your table structure, something like this should work:

```
SELECT document_type 
FROM taxes t join notification n on t.document_id = n.document_id 
WHERE n.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT taxes.document_type
FROM notification, taxes
WHERE notification.notification_id = ?
  AND notification.document_id = taxes.document_id
```

Comment: you should try to use ANSI-92 compliant queries instead of ANSI-89. the     FROM tablename, tablename2     structure has been depreciated.

Comment: The word you want is deprecated, not depriciated.  And no sane database vendor is going to do away with the ANSI-89 syntax any time soon.